# update in sql with inner join and having

Tags: sql, select

hi i want to copy value from LEAD2 to LEAD1 . I have the query that select these columns but i dont know how update `set LEAD2=LEAD1`. Here is the select query:

```
    SELECT
        a.lead_id AS LEAD1
        , b.lead_id AS LEAD2
    FROM
        dbo.spirulina AS a
            INNER JOIN dbo.spirulina AS b
                ON a.PHONEHOME = b.PHONEHOME
    WHERE
        (a.lead_id IS NOT NULL)
        AND (b.lead_id IS NULL)
    GROUP BY
        a.lead_id
        , b.lead_id
    HAVING
        (COUNT(a.PHONEHOME) > 1)
```

Comment: Can you please describe what exactly are you trying to do here? Cause there could be an easy way of achieving what you might be trying to achieve via this query.

Comment: Looks like you want to set lead_id to null when a phonehome is in multiple rows?

Comment: @dotjoe sorry my fault. lead2=lead1 ... no lead1=lead2

Comment: Is this for SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL... ? Always add a tag for the DBMS you are using when asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is set the table to UPDATE where you want to change the value. From what it looks like you are trying to deal with lead_id with multiple entries of PhoneHome. The query below may return the result set:

```
SELECT 
    PHONEHOME
    , COUNT(1)[Count]
FROM
    dbo.spirulina
GROUP BY
    PHONEHOME
HAVING
    COUNT(PHONEHOME) > 1
```

If those are the records you want to update, simply update the table and set the column(s) value

```
UPDATE
    dbo.spirulina
SET
    lead_id = NULL
FROM
    dbo.spirulina
GROUP BY
    PHONEHOME
HAVING
    COUNT(PHONEHOME) > 1
```

Comment: Yes i ve already do that by through exception: Incorrect syntax near group by

Comment: What RDMS are using? It really depends as some handle joins differently in update statements. Please advise. See @TT.'s comment above.